# We have [some things or something] in common

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> Jan and I have [some things / something] in common.
>   First, we like Sailormoon
>   Second, we like cats
>   Third, we have long hair

I think **some things** is the right choice,
because I have listed three things that both Jan and I have,
but "**have something in common**" is here:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have_something_in_common

Does this mean that I am wrong if I pick **some things**?

Comment: In dictionary definitions/patterns, *something* is usually a placeholder for a noun phrase.

Comment: With a list (the *things*) I would use "some things", though *something* is not specific regarding plurality.

Comment: Here, "some things" is fine.  When we say that we have "something in common" with another person it is usually one thing. *I have something in common with Jan. We both grew up near the ocean.* It there are several things, we'd probably say *I have a few things in common with Jan. We both grew up near the ocean. We both had a pet dog. And we both are good at math*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say

> We have **some things** in common

people may expect a list of those *things*

but if you say

> We have **something** in common

there is more an air of mystery about what it is that is common

> There's **something** about her, but I just can't put my finger on it.

which may mean there are attributes about her which taken together are attractive but escape articulation, there is more a sense of *mystery*.

If you say

> *Something*'s in the air tonight

it may be the weather, or the mood, or the music, usually *positive*, but if you say

> *Some things* are in the air tonight

it may be understood to mean bugs, smoke, or air pollution, probably *negative*.

I think in your example

> some things

is perfectly acceptable since they are enumerated, just as you might say

> We have a *few things* in common.
>   ... list...